# Why could Luke sense the good in Darth Vader, but Obi-wan could not?

Tags: star-wars

During their final duel on the Death Star, why could Obi-Wan not sense the good in Darth Vader, the way Luke later did?

In Episode 6, Luke says to Vader:

> I can feel the good in you.

Luke's senses were not as deep as Obi-Wan's, who had years of training and knew Anakin inside and out. So he should have sensed less.

Comment: I suspect that Obi-wan is somewhat distracted by the fact that his surrogate son has just murdered everyone he ever cared about along with rooms filled with children.

Comment: when obi won fights vader in episode 3, vader is at the pinnacle of his darkness, when he fights vader in 4 vader doesn't know his kids are alive still. by the time luke fights him in episode 6, hes starting to have feelings towards his children and has the emperor trying to "hurt" them specifically which is re-awaking his humanity.

Comment: I seem to recall Obi-Wan not being particularly good with the Living Force.

Comment: @Himarm I suspect you can dig up some supporting dialog and turn that into an answer

Comment: Luke was not the only one. Padme said the same about Vader that there is still good in him

Comment: @Thomas I think in Padme's case that it was just wishful thinking; she was someone trying to come to grips with the horrible actions of a loved one-- but that's just wild supposition on my part.

Comment: I'm not so sure especially with all the prophecies and even force/luck jarjar around.Also she said exactly the same words with the same pronouncation as luke a few decades later so I take it it was a hint/premonition at episode 6 and thus a bit more than just wishful thinking

Comment: Maybe he simply didn't believe it could be there and therefore did not see it. (ha it almost sounds deep)

Comment: Could just be Intuition and not the supernatural jedi mind thingy action, he "feels" what he wants to be true.

Comment: @IG_42 that sounds like what yoda always said about visions that one must be cautious to not cloud them with their own feelings and fears

Comment: Who's to say he didn't? IMO, that's why he could never pull the trigger.

Comment: I think because at the time obi was fighting darth vader in the fourth mvoie, vader suddenly felt extreme anger, now that he is seeing his archenemy, but then after he killed him he wasn't that angry. darth vader was super angry when seeing OBI but that was mainly the only time he was super mad. also in the thrid movie he didn't sense any good becuase he had just turned to the dark side and all of vaders anger was suddenly spilling fourth. but when luke saw him, vader wasn't very mad, first: he was his father, second, he wasn't his total enemy and he didn't 100% hate him

Answer (score 23):

1. Luke is more powerful than Obi-Wan. Both Vader ("**The Force is strong with this one**" from *Ep. IV*) and Emperor ("**The Force is strong with him**. The son of Skywalker must not become a Jedi" from *Ep. V*; and "you must bring him before me. **He has grown strong**. Only together can we turn him to the Dark Side of the Force" from *Ep. VI*) acknowledge it.

   In Legends canon, Luke explicitly is noted to have the same super-high Midichlorian count as Anakin, meaning he's stronger in the Force than Obi-Wan
2. Obi-Wan especially isn't good at "minding the Living Force", as Qui-Gon noted in Episode 1.
3. Luke has familial relationship with Vader, which probably helps attune their feelings and force connections to each other. Not 100% certain from canon, but can be inferred from, for example, Leia also sensing Luke's distress when saving him in Cloud City at the end of Episode V.

   Similarly, Vader can sense Luke's presence even when the Emperor cannot in Episode VI:

   > Darth Vader: My son is with them.
   >   The Emperor: Are you sure?
   >   Darth Vader: I have *felt* him, my master.
   >   The Emperor: Strange that I have not. I wonder if your feelings on this matter are clear, Lord Vader.
4. Luke is inherently compassionate in general (and this especially intertwines with Vader being his father) - which is in contrast with Jedi (like Obi-Wan) who are trained NOT to emotionally entangle themselves since a very young age:

   > Darth Vader: He will come to me?
   >   The Emperor: I have foreseen it. **His compassion for you will be his undoing**. He will come to you and then you will bring him before me.
   >   Darth Vader: As you wish.
5. Obi-Wan is prejudiced against Anakin - this was the man who was his friend **and** "**The Chosen One**", who betrayed both their friendship and entire Jedi Order and entire Republic - and **murdered a Temple full of Jedi younglings**. Luke didn't have that coloring his feelings. *(H/t for @Thomas noted in the comments)*

Comment: I think #3 is the most convincing answer, and the benefit of the familial relationship between Vader and Luke is explicit when Vader senses Luke on the forest moon of Endor but the Emperor does not.

Comment: I'm not sure if I buy your first two points. Both Vader and Palpatine say that Luke is strong with the Force, but they make no comparison to Obi-Wan, and don't Midichlorian counts indicate *potential,* not ability? Secondly, Obi-Wan in TPM is very different from Obi-Wan in ANH.

Comment: @KSmarts - Luke wins the fight with Vader. Obi-Wan loses it.

Comment: @DVK Well, that raises the question of whether Obi-Wan ever *intended* to win that fight, which is, AFAIK, a matter of interpretation. I hold that he did not, so that is not a valid comparison, but that may be getting into opinion-based discussion.

Comment: @KSmarts - "Escape is not his plan" - said the guy whose PREVIOUS tactical assessment of Obi-Wan was "Hey I'll rush a guy standing on the high ground over lava".

Comment: In addition to the points one thing is also the case: Obiwan has prejudice against anakin after the betrayal while luke does not have it and padme she was still in love with anakin. As it was often noted by yoda,.... even in the films emotions especially strong or dark ones can cloud ones perception even through the force

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct would be to say that Darth Vader had compassion for Luke, because Luke was his son, and not for Obi Wan (who was his enemy), and so Luke was able to pick up on that.  Also, Darth Vader may have been "softened" by Luke's attempts to reach out to him, and this may have made his feelings come more to the surface.

I also think #3 is a strong possibility. Luke had a connection with Laia because she was his sister (after Darth Vader cuts his hand off, he reaches out to her telepathically.)

Comment: This is my thought as well.  Anakin has feelings for Luke and did not want to destroy him.  Luke picks up on this and senses the "good in him".  However Anakin hates Obi-Wan and has no good feelings at all for him when he encounters OBi-Wan on the Death Star.

Answer (score -1):

"I hate to be the only non-scientist to point this out but..." 
It was simply because Anakin is Luke's Father, and Luke is his son. 
"The Force is strong with this one."

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, are those quotes from the screenplay or film? Do you have any other evidence to suggest that it is "Simply because they're related"?